# How to prove that a regular hexagon covers the euclidian plane without overlapping and gaps?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

My question is:

> How to prove that a regular hexagon covers the euclidian plane without overlapping and gaps?

I think it would be the same as proofing the case that an equilateral triangle is covering the plane without overlapping and gaps. I would love to get some literature about it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All internal angles of an hexagon are $2\pi/3$. Hence you can put 3 of them together to "cover" the whole angle $3\cdot 2\pi/3=2\pi$. Now keep doing the same at all vertices of all hexagons (those that are already there and those that you keep attaching).